# Why Github does not automatically update the file comparison between two PRs?

Tags: git, github, diff, git-merge

I created three branches except `main`: `b-release`, `b-A`, `b-B`. And the `b-A` is created based on `release-branch`, while `b-B` is based on `b-A`.

```
main --- b-release
            |       
           b-A  ---  b-B
```

I also created three PRs:

1. `PR-release` (compare to `main`): this pr is the changeLog consisting of `PR-b-A` and `PR-b-B`
2. `PR-b-A` (compare to `b-release`): this pr is the changes in `b-A`
3. `PR-b-B` (compare to `b-release`): this pr is the changes in `b-B`

The purpose is to merge `PR-release` into `main` **after** `b-A` and `b-B` merge into `b-release`.

However, after I merged the `PR-b-A` into `PR-release`, the files comparison in `PR-b-B` did not update. Even if I tried to change base to `main` and change back to `b-release`, it still was not changed.

Does anyone know how to update file changes on `PR-b-B`?

Comment: are you editing the same files? `PR-b-B` will only show the new changes that `PR-b-B` would introduce. If the edits in `PR-b-A` was on files unrelated to the files in `PR-b-B` then nothing will change.

Comment: Not sure about GitHub, but it might only show the diff `release b-B` and not the diff `main b-B` (maybe it can be selected somewhere? GitLab has dropdowns to compare different versions of a PR/MR with different base/reference commits)

Comment: The question is if you did the changes in `b-A` before or after branching `b-B` off it. If this was done **before**, the diff should change when `PR-b-A` is merged because the changes of `b-A` were on `b-B` as well and are now integrated in `b-release` (hence should no longer be in the diff). If the changes on `b-A` were done **after** branching `b-B` off it, the changes of `b-A` were never on `b-B` and the diff would therefore not be affected by a *unrelated* merge (of `PR-b-A`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diff displayed in a PR is the diff between :

- the head of the branch (`b-B` in your case)
- the fork point between that branch and the target branch (the fork point between `b-B` and `b-release`)

If you look closely at how the branches behave : if you update the `b-release` branch, the fork point does not change (see diagram below).

If you want to change what is displayed in the PR, you will have to change branch `b-B`.
For example : run `git rebase b-release` after `b-A` has been merged. You will have to force push to origin after that.

---

Taking your diagram :

```
# before merging b-A :
main --- b-release
            \       
             * --- * --- b-A  --- * --- * --- b-B

# after merging b-A :
main ---   x     ---  b-release
            \              /
             * --- * --- b-A  --- * --- * --- b-B

# the fork point with 'b-release' is till commit 'x'

# to update the fork point : change the history of branch b-B
# after 'git rebase b-release' :
main ---   x     ---  b-release
            \              /  \
             * --- * --- b-A   * --- * --- b-B
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe `rebase` works (I like the diagram!). I actually have lots of commits merged into `b-release`. If I do `rebase`, I need to fix lots of conflicts commit by commit. To make things easier, I just did `git pull` and fix conflicts all together. The files comparison is updated after I push the changes!

Comment: One question: do you think whether it would happen again, if `b-B` was also built based on `b-release`?

Comment: It woudl be the same : `b-B` is already based on `b-release` (in your diagram, just imagine you erase the `b-A` reference)