# Why aren't all of the differences between my branch and dev showing in the PR?

Tags: git, github, merge, diff

Last week I merged a feature branch into our dev branch for testing. The testers found a bug so I branched again from dev to fix it. Yesterday, the merge were reverted since it wasn't ready in time for release. After making some revisions, I opened a new PR with that new branch. Now, in the GitHub `Files changed` tab, it only shows the newer revisions (~50 lines instead of the ~1000 that it actually is).

Looking at the files on dev and myBranch I've confirmed that the changes were successfully reverted and exist only on myBranch.

`git diff dev..myBranch` only shows the newer revisions, but `git diff <latest-dev-commit-hash>..<latest-myBranch-commit-hash>` shows all of the differences between the files.

It seems to me that the differences are measured by the commits rather than the actual differences. Can I force GitHub to compare each file and update the PR so that reviewers can see all of the differences?

Comment: By reverting a merge, you have effectively said that if those same commits come up again, you don't want them again; they are already in the history of dev, although their _effect_ has been undone by the revert.

Comment: There was a similar question yesterday. GitHub shows the diff from the merge base (common ancestor). If you type `git diff myBranch...dev` (or `git diff "$(git merge-base myBranch dev)" dev`), do you get a matching output?

Comment: @knittl Thanks for the comment. Yep, I compared the outputs of the `..` and `...` diffs and they are identical. Do you think the similar question would be useful? Could you link it?

Comment: @matt Does that mean if/when this PR is merged it won't have those changes that were reverted?

Comment: @Chris I had to find it first :) here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477862/why-github-does-not-automatically-update-the-file-comparison-between-two-prs

Comment: It could mean that. Reverting a merge is a tricky thing. See, always see, the canonical discussion: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Comment: @matt Thanks for that, it's the exact issue I'm having.

Comment: @knittl Thanks for the link. While it may not be the exact solution it definitely helped me frame the problem in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem due to the way revert works. Once it's explained, it makes perfect sense, but it's not intuitive prior to that... (**tl;dr:** glance at the bolded sentence below for a hint as to why.)

When you revert a commit, you create a *new* commit which is the opposite of the original commit, so effectively it is an undo, but now you have 2 commits: one does X and then one undoes X. Together on the same branch in the proper order, those 2 commits have no effect.

When you revert a *merge* commit (usually from a completed PR, and reverting back to the first parent), you are doing the same thing, but this time you are making a new single commit which reverses all of the commits brought in by that merge (or PR). An interesting side note to this is if your merge (or PR) contained only 1 new commit, then whether you reverted that one commit or the merge commit wouldn't make a difference; the result would be the same. As soon as you have more than 1 commit in a merge, then it's oftentimes easier to just revert the merge commit, compared to individually reverting all of the commits in the merged branch.

The confusion comes in later when you decide you want to bring your branch back in again. Maybe you decided you really did want your code as is, or maybe you fixed a bug and added a new commit (your scenario). Either way, when you try to re-merge your branch again your commits won't show up! **The reason is because those commits are already on the target branch so the new merge can't bring them in *again*.**

So what can you do? You have options:

1. Revert the revert. Sometimes this makes sense. On throwaway integration branches such as `next` or `pu` (from [gitworkflow](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows)) I would probably choose this. If you do this on a permanent branch, please be kind and explain in the commit details what the heck is going on because reverted reverts are confusing, without knowing the reasons. For further reading, [here's an explanation from Linus Torvalds in 2008](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) which discusses when and why you should revert a revert.
2. Rewrite the commit IDs on your branch. You probably know that you can force a merge commit with `git merge --no-ff some-branch`, but did you know you can [force a rewrite with rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---no-ff) too? The syntax is the same: `git rebase --no-ff commit-ID` where "commit-ID" is the parent of the first commit on your branch (typically the merge-base of your branch and the target branch). All this does is take your commits and re-write them "now" which changes only the commit ID (and committer date and author) just like if you did a regular rebase.
3. Rewrite the commit IDs on another branch. I can't think of a good use case for this, but conceptually some people find it easier to understand this since they are wary of the rebase command. Create a new branch from your starting point, switch to it (check it out), and then cherry-pick each of the commits from your branch to the new branch. This will rewrite the commit IDs, and you can even do it all in one shot with a range of commits like this: `git cherry-pick parent-of-first-commit..last-commit` (**Update**: A potential generic use case for this would be if you want to bring in reverted commits from a protected branch that you cannot rewrite, or there are commits after the reverted commits you do not wish to rewrite.)

After you've done any of those options, try the merge again, and your commits will show up in the PR.